# Starting Qt application on Boot up- Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface, qtandroidextras

I know how to start an android application on BOOT of device. I have done that in Java using a BroadcastReceiver. However, my isue is something else. I'm kinda stuck at this problem:

Problem:
I'm using Qt for Android. I have a Qt file which listens for TCP/IP connections. Once the connection with the client is established, I start displaying images and sounds. However, I want this listening to be a background service which starts on boot of device. And only when the connection is established should the activity to display the images and sounds start. Any ideas on how to begin/implement? Do I have to use JNI?

Comment: Can someone plz help me with this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286758/qt-android-cant-listen-to-os-intents-ex-receive-boot-completed

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported issue how to build background services with Qt:

[Build background service with Qt on android](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37221)

For the time being, there is the `QtService/Activity* thing from there, but it may be handier in future releases as the time goes ahead.